# Will asynchronous behavior of node create problems for auction/eCommerce websites

Tags: node.js

i have been looking at nodejs and have been considering building a auction site with it. however I have been told that it may not be suitable for because of its asynchronous behavior and  suggested to use blocking code such as php/ruby. i.e. If a bidder1 places a bid and a bidder2 places a second bid shortly afterwards but node processes bidder2 before bidder1, then the bid price will go out of sequence. I know this can be trapped with logic but is there any truth in this?

Thanks

Comment: It will only be a problem if you make it a problem. Because you have control over mitigating this or not. With that said, the statement that blocking code would be "better" is *odd* - if two people send a bit at the same time, it will be down to their network speeds to determine who is actually first. Neither PHP nor Ruby will save you from that. Besides, I'm not sure they are fully blocking as that wording implies, otherwise that means that *the entire server hangs* when a bid is processed. Surely, that's not something anyone wants, as you're wide open to DoS attacks.

Comment: There are thousands of auction/eCommerce sites running asynchronous code that works, so I don't understand the motivation for this question. If you need to guarantee order, that can be done.

Comment: @ggorlen also, it should be noted that even though JS has asynchronisiy, it's not like it executes stuff in random order. If bid2 comes before bid3 but both are delayed to be processed because, bid1 is being currently processed, then you'd *still* do bid1 -> bid2 -> bid3. Unless you are running all bid processing in separate threads *and* the threads are not synchronised. This is actually a problem you run with Java and the like more, since that uses multithreading for asynchronicity, JS (by default) doesn't and delayed code execution is still run in order.

Comment: Sure, but it seems like it depends on the design. If making a bid involves requests to external vendors to check prices or stock, for example, I can see scenarios where race conditions can arise, and of course there are corresponding solutions. Some database operations may not be serial and can introduce ordering problems. These problems can exist in just about any computing environment. It's just too broad to say much more than this.

Comment: That problem with a server and multiple clients competing for resources is mostly a database problem and a server-code design problem.  You don't fix that by picking PHP.  You will have to be concurrency-aware in your programming no matter which language you pick for the back-end.